# jQuery using outerwidth to set element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, margin

Is there a way with jQuery that I can use `outerwidth` to get the width of an element from `.entry 1` to `.entry 6` (that doesn't have a width specified in CSS) and then have the container to be centered on the page?

Basically, I'm using a dynamic width for entries,  but no dynamic width for the container they're in. This is so that when the user resizes their window (and for different screen resolutions), there is  the most amount of posts per row possible. I want a script that measures the posts on the first row and sets the width of the `div #content` so I can use `margin auto`.

Example: [here](http://idkheylol.tumblr.com/)

Comment: No need to explain yourself, all questions are welcome if they meet the requirements of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Can you post your code directly into the question?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/centered.html

Answer (score 1):

```
//CSS // centers an object in its "relative" parent
.element {
     margin: 0 auto;
}

//JS // places outwidth of eleID1 as the width of eleID2
$(".eleID2").width($("#eleID1").outerWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

With the javascript width functions (and jQuery equivalents) you always get the current widths , no matter if you declared it in css or not.

If i got you right, you could just loop over the 6 entries, add their widths together and move the container 50% from left and 50% of its own width back (It should be centered then).

Comment: I cannot do that, because on smaller screens, there will be less posts in a row, and on larger ones there will be more.

Comment: You should get responsive then and use the media tags like `@media (max-width: 480px) {}`